# Android sqlcipher attach database giving transaction error

Tags: android, sqlcipher

Hi i'm using sqlcipher in an android app i'm trying to encrypt an unencrypted database so currently i'm getting an error saying (cannot attach database within transaction) so here's my code please help me preferably with a working example

```
  import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;


import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;
//import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
//import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DictDatabase {

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "words_"+MainModule.DICT;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "dict_"+MainModule.DICT;
    private static final String DATABASE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/beta_"+MainModule.DICT+".sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int OPEN_READWRITE = 0 ;

public static final String REC_WORDID = "wId";
public static final String REC_WORD2 = "wNormed";
public static final String REC_WORD = "wWord";
public static final String REC_LANG2 = "wLanguage";
    public static final String REC_DESCRIPTION = "wGrammar";
    public static final String REC_SOUND = "wSound";
    public static final String REC_HASH = "wHash";

    private static final String CLASSTAG = "DictDatabase";
     private  SQLiteDatabase mDb;
     private final Context mCtx;
     private DbController dbController;
    //private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data/data/babla.dict/files/" + "beta_deen.sqlite";

private static class DbController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
     private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private final Context mCtx;
    private static final String words = "CREATE TABLE `words_"+MainModule.DICT+"` (wId INTEGER,wWord ,wNormed ,wLanguage ,wGrammar ,wSound ,wHash )";
    private static final String phrases =
        " CREATE TABLE `phrases_"+MainModule.DICT+"` (Id INTEGER,cat,catPos INTEGER,subCat,subCatPos INTEGER,subSubCat,subSubCatPos INTEGER,entryPos INTEGER,text1,text2,description)";
    private static final String dict =
   " CREATE TABLE `dict"+MainModule.DICT+"` (dId ,dWdeId INTEGER,dWenId INTEGER,dOrigin ,dStatus ,dChangeDate ,transWord1Id ,transWord2Id ,transWord1 ,transWord2 )";
    private static final String enFlex =
    "CREATE TABLE `enFlex` (flexId ,flexPrincipleForm, flexTimeId INTEGER ,flexPersonId, flexGenderId,flexWord,flexWordNormed , flexWordUrl)";
    private static final String flexPersonsGenders =
        "CREATE TABLE `flexPersonsGenders` (fpgLanguage ,fpgPersonId,fpgGenderId ,fpgName)";
    private static final String flexTimes = "CREATE TABLE `flexTimes` (ftId,ftLanguage,ftTimeId,ftName,ftComment)";
    private static final String normalTimesFlex = "CREATE TABLE `normalTimesFlex` (ntfLanguage ,ntfTime  INTEGER )";
    String insertCommand = "insert into "+DATABASE+".words_"+MainModule.DICT+" SELECT * from words_"+MainModule.DICT;
    String insertCommand2 = "insert into "+DATABASE+".dict_"+MainModule.DICT+" SELECT * from dict"+MainModule.DICT;
    String insertCommand3 = "insert into "+DATABASE+".phrases"+MainModule.DICT+" SELECT * from dict"+MainModule.DICT;
    String insertCommand4 = "insert into "+DATABASE+".enFlex SELECT * from enFlex";
    String insertCommand5 = "insert into "+DATABASE+".flexPersonsGenders SELECT * from flexPersonsGenders";
    String insertCommand6 = "insert into "+DATABASE+".flexTimes SELECT * from flexTimes";
    String insertCommand7 = "insert into "+DATABASE+".normalTimesFlex SELECT * from normalTimesFlex";

    DbController(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                     mCtx= context;
     }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDb = db;
        //mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(mCtx.getFilesDir() +"/"+"beta_"+MainModule.DICT, "", null);
        //mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mCtx.getFilesDir() +"/"+"beta_"+MainModule.DICT,"",null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        mDb.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '"+DATABASE+"' AS encrypted KEY 'p@ssW0rd';");
        mDb.execSQL(words);mDb.execSQL(phrases);mDb.execSQL(dict);mDb.execSQL(enFlex);mDb.execSQL(flexPersonsGenders);mDb.execSQL(flexTimes);
        mDb.execSQL(normalTimesFlex);
        mDb.execSQL(insertCommand);mDb.execSQL(insertCommand2);mDb.execSQL(insertCommand3);mDb.execSQL(insertCommand4);mDb.execSQL(insertCommand5);
        mDb.execSQL(insertCommand6);mDb.execSQL(insertCommand7);
        mDb.execSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('"+DATABASE +"');");
        mDb.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE "+DATABASE+";");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

is this how its done or i'm placing things in the wrong places some please help even if with an example

Answer (score 0):

You need to call like this way `db.execSQL("ATTACH 'hq_db' AS hq_db;");` before you start any kind of transaction. Do the attachment first, and then start the transaction.

Comment: Thanks man for your help but this didn't help I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run individual insert/select statements for each table, the `sqlcipher_export` convenience function does this work for you.  For an example of migrating an unencrypted database into a SQLCipher database, take a look at [this](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/b7ae8174f32342b30990b312daee6053bb0be49b/app/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/ImportUnencryptedDatabaseTest.java) test case from the SQLCipher for Android [test suite](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests) we publish.

Comment: hi thanks for the response the app always fail when it comes to the attach Database as shown in your example i get an unable to open database what could be the problem

Comment: When running this on your emulator, use adb shell to verify whether or not both database files already exist.  Also, can you pull down the test suite and run it locally.  This will help verify whether or not there is a problem specific to your configuration.

Comment: the database file both exist but the encrypted one does not have any of the tables